From which Pirates of the Caribbean movie does this clip come from?
I am making a school project, and I need some stock footage. I found a perfect clip here at 3:20. 



Does anybody know which Pirates of the Caribbean movie this clip is from? 

Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man’s Chest.
It is the attack of the giant Kraken.

Thanks for answering but follow up question: at what time does it show the ship zooming in specifically?
